# What is the usage of Configured class in Hadoop programs?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, toolrunner

Most of Hadoop MapReduce programs are like this:

```
public class MyApp extends Configured Implements Tool {
    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Job job = new Job(getConf());
        /* process command line options */
        return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new MyApp(), args);
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }
}
```

What is the usage of `Configured`? As `Tool` and `Configured` both have `getConf()` and `setConf()` in common. What does it provide to our application?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Configured` is an implementation class of the interface `Configurable`. `Configured` is the base class which has the implementations of `getConf()` and `setConf()`.

Merely extending this base class enables the class that extends this to be configured using a `Configuration` and there are more than one implementations for `Configuration`.

When your code executes the following line,

```
ToolRunner.run(new MyApp(), args);
```

Internally it will do this

```
ToolRunner.run(tool.getConf(), tool, args);
```

In the above case `tool` is the `MyApp` class instance which is an implementation of `Tool` which just as you said has `getConf()` but it is just as an interface. The implementation is coming from `Configured` base class. If you avoid extending `Configured` class in the above code, then you will have to do the `getConf()` and `setConf()` implementations on your own.

Answer (score 3):

[`Configured`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configured.html) is a default implementation of the [`Configurable`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configurable.html) interface - basically its `setConf` method retains a private instance variable to the passed `Configuration` object and `getConf()` returns that reference

[`Tool`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/Tool.html) is an extension of the `Configurable` interface, providing an addition `run(..)` method and is used with [`ToolRunner`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/ToolRunner.html) to parse out command line options (using the [`GenericOptionsParser`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/GenericOptionsParser.html)) and build a `Configuration` object which is then passed to the `setConf(..)` method.

Your main class will typically extend Configured such that the Configurable interface methods required in Tool will be implemented for you.

In general you should be using the ToolRunner utility class to launch your MapReduce jobs as it handles the common task of parsing out command line arguments and building the Configuration object. I'd look at the API Docs for ToolRunner for more info.