# passing argument "args" from main class to Map class

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, command-line-arguments

exemple : jar class arg1 arg2 arg3

arg 1 for input format , arg 2 for output format like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));
.
.
.
.
}
```

i need to send arg3 "args[2]" to map class .....

```
public class JoinMultiMap extends MapReduceBase
  implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> 
{
i need arg3 her
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Configuration](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html) class to set and get custom configuration properties like this:

In your Driver code:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
// other imports ignored for brevity
// ...

public class YourDriver extends Configured implements Tool {
  public int run(String[] args) {
    Configuration conf = getConf();
    conf.set("yourcustom.property", args[2]);
    // other driver code ignored
    // ...
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)  {
    int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new YourDriver(), args);
    System.exit(res);
  }
}
```

From the Mapper code:

```
public class YourMapper extends Mapper<...> {
  private String yourArgument;

  @Override
    protected void setup(Context context) {
        Configuration c = context.getConfiguration();
        yourArgument = c.get("yourcustom.property");
    }

  @Override
  protected void map(...) {
    // use your argument
  }
}
```

Comment: but what is getConf(); in Configuration conf = getConf();

Comment: `getConf()` is just a convenience method provided by the [Configured](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configured.html) class which gives back the configuration object set by `setConf()` method. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134865/what-is-the-usage-of-configured-class-in-hadoop-programs.